# extract all xml child nodes

Tags: xml, python-3.x

I have some xml with the the following structure, and am trying to extract all the collaborator strings into a list for further analysis

```
<sponsors>
  <lead_sponsor>University of Erlangen-Nürnberg Medical School</lead_sponsor> 
  <collaborator>University Hospital Regensburg</collaborator> 
  <collaborator>Wuerzburg University Hospital</collaborator> 
  <collaborator>University Hospital, Essen</collaborator> 
  <collaborator>German Research Foundation</collaborator> 
</sponsors>
```

The code I've come up with seem to pull the first collaborator one ok adn puts in a '???' if there are no collaborators, but not the remaining ones if there are more than one and I can't figure out why. Looking at similar questions on here would seem to suggest it'd work, but I'm clearly misunderstanding something. Here's what I've got:

```
tree = etree.parse(infile)
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in tree.iter(tag='sponsors'):
    child = elem.find('collaborator')
    if child is not None:
        co = child.text
    else:
        co = "???"
    collaborator.append(co)
    print(co)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that the for loop is not iterating on each child element, is just getting the first child of sponsors and exiting. 
Something along these lines should work:

```
tree = etree.parse(infile)
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in tree.getiterator():
    if elem.tag!='sponsors':
        if elem.tag == 'collaborator':
            co = elem.text
        else:
            co = "???"
        collaborator.append(co)   
        print(co)
```